# Select function in non blocking sockets

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm building an online game client and when I try to connect to an offline server, my client freezes so I wanted to use non blocking sockets which suits games since there are other tasks need to be done while connecting to the server.

While using non blocking sockets, the `connect` function always returns the same value regardless of the result, so people here recommended using the `select` function to find the result of the connection request.

(setting the non blocking socket before connection)

```
u_long iMode=1;
ioctlsocket(hSocket,FIONBIO,&iMode);
```

---

(setting the sockets sets)

```
FD_ZERO(&Write);
FD_ZERO(&Err);
FD_SET(hSocket, &Write);
FD_SET(hSocket, &Err);
```

---

```
TIMEVAL Timeout;

int TimeoutSec = 10; // timeout after 10 seconds
Timeout.tv_sec = TimeoutSec;
Timeout.tv_usec = 0;
int iResult = select(0,     //ignored
                     NULL,      //read
                     &(client.Write),    //Write Check
                     &(client.Err),      //Error Check
                     &Timeout);

if(iResult)
{
}
else
{
    message_login("Error","Can't connect to the server");
}
```

The `select` function always returns -1, why?

Comment: Is Write identical to client.Write? Is Err identical to client.Err? Where is hSocket coming from? Your error message in case of iResult==0 is not correct.

Comment: You should also check `WSAGetLastError` for error code if `iResult == -1` => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: yes it's identical as i said it's part of my code since it's not in one file,
regardless of what it returns but it returns the same thing always

Comment: Did you previously call WSAStartup ?

Answer (score 2):

When `select()` returns -1 (`SOCKET_ERROR`), use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why it failed.

If the socket is in the `Err` set when `select()` exits, use `getsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR)` to retrieve the socket error code that tells you why `connect()` failed.

`if(iResult)` evaluates as true for any non-zero value, including -1.  You need to use `if(iResult > 0)` instead, as `iResult` will report the number of sockets that are signaled in *any* `fd_set`, 0 on timeout, and -1 on failure.

Try something more like this instead:

```
u_long iMode = 1;
if (ioctlsocket(hSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    int errCode = WSAGetLastError();
    // use errCode as needed...
    message_login("Error", "Can't set socket to non-blocking, error: ..."); // however you supply a variable value to your message...
}
```

```
if (connect(client.hSocket, ...) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    int errCode = WSAGetLastError();
    if (errCode != WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        // use errCode as needed...
        message_login("Error", "Can't connect to the server, error: ..."); // however you supply a variable value...
    }
    else
    {
        // only in this condition can you now use select() to wait for connect() to finish...
    }
}
```

```
TIMEVAL Timeout;

int TimeoutSec = 10; // timeout after 10 seconds
Timeout.tv_sec = TimeoutSec;
Timeout.tv_usec = 0;

int iResult = select(0,     //ignored
                     NULL,      //read
                     &(client.Write),    //Write Check
                     &(client.Err),      //Error Check
                     &Timeout);

if (iResult > 0)
{
    if (FD_ISSET(client.hSocket, &(client.Err)))
    {
        DWORD errCode = 0;
        int len = sizeof(errCode);
        if (getsockopt(client.hSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&errCode, &len) == 0)
        {
             // use errCode as needed...
             message_login("Error", "Can't connect to the server, error: ..."); // however you supply a variable value to your message...
        }
        else
            message_login("Error", "Can't connect to the server, unknown reason");
    }
    else
        message_login("Success", "Connected to the server");
}
else if (iResult == 0)
{
    message_login("Error", "Timeout connecting to the server");
}
else
{
    int errCode = WSAGetLastError();
    // use errCode as needed...
    message_login("Error", "Can't connect to the server, error: ..."); // however you supply a variable value to your message...
}
```